# Is it possible to sort data in a textview?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I am using 'Codeofaninja' . 
[android table scroll code](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html)

He generates data. I replaced that with an sqlite database. It works well but...
I need to sort and the displays are textviews with tablerows.
Should I use listviews instead of the textviews/tablerows?
I have seen examples of data being sorted in a collection. I have my data in lists already but I have read that textviews have performance problems.
If the answer is listviews then I have to redesign the views which I am trying to not do. But if technology says I must then so be it.
So I have come up with 2 options:
1:textview gets repopulated with list after any data actions.
2:listview is where data is manipulated then stored back to db. Then I need to put a listview in the relativelayout view?

I have tried deleting the tablerows from the textview and reading data back in but this proves slow.

I searched on textviews and listviews and have seen many examples but it is still not clear as to what method is the preferred.
Thank you for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the sorting is independent of the view. You sort the data in the collection (list, array, etc.) first, then use the ListAdapter (or ArrayAdapter, .etc) to populate the view.

From what you described, it seems the textviews are re-created every time, i.e, if you have 10 rows, each row has 3 textviews, did you create 30 textviews? In that case, sure it has performance problem. Try reading up on ViewHolder for ListView 
[Android Viewholder implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465275/android-viewholder-implementation)

Comment: I generated 100 database records and that equals 300 textviews. When I first started into this design I didnt catch the process of listview versus textview. Your answer here confirms that listview is the standard or should be. So this is great solid direction. I was always assuming I could load and throw data anyway I saw fit.

Comment: I flagged this as an answer because of the performance issue i was noticing. This answer stopped me in my tracks from going any further into trying to cobble any more code around the textview usage.

Comment: I am giving the user the option of pressing a header label to sort asc or desc. The whole view then displays the new result. So from what you say here the label press then sorts the array and the array redisplayed. By using the setup of the previous answer the listview will automatically display based upon a change event trigger.

Comment: Yes, you just need to call notifyDataChanged function of the adapter. The rest is automatic

Answer (score 1):

It is superior to use the idea of loading some data at a time. Both Android **ListView** and **RecyclerView** virtually loads data when required, and removes data when they are no longer needed.
One good tutorial about ListView @ [Populating a ListView With Data](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/). Tell us what you think of it.

The only drawback for these GUI classes is when you only have small amount of data to show, which is not likely, from your post.

Comment: Same comment applies to both answers here. [
 
I generated 100 database records and that equals 300 textviews. When I first started into this design I didnt catch the process of listview versus textview. Your answer here confirms that listview is the standard or should be. So this is great solid direction. I was always assuming I could load and throw data anyway I saw fit.]

Comment: My reason for getting stuck is the layout is built dynamically. I am trying to maintain this design because I have the number of columns generated by another table.

Comment: I like this answer. This answer is truly secondary, meaning I will have to use it after I get the sort array down implemented.

Comment: @PaulMoore, Don't worry about sorting the array yet. You have options for sorting like Collections.sort() or use CursorLoader class which uses SQL to sort.

Comment: @PaulMoore, For the layout issue and sorting, pls just post another question(s) for them. btw, It is more difficult to build a dynamic layout of variable columns. I suggest make a layout with few columns for now, actually they are few UI elements inside ListView UI.